# eloquent go to the wrong table just on store method

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

i have a problem that make my head blow about eloquent went to the wrong table here my code for my activity model

```
class Activity extends Model{
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'activities';

protected $guarded = ['id'];

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

and the problem is when i store to the database, eloquent went to the wrong table
here is my store method

```
public function store(StoreActivityRequest $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required|unique:activies'
    ]);

    Activity::create($validatedData);
    return redirect('/activities')->with('success', 'Tindakan Berhasil Ditambahkan');
}
```

this is my customrequest (actually my laravel make it by default)

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreActivityRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        //
    ];
}
}
```

here is the message

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'klinik_app.activies' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `activies` where `slug` = konsultasi)
```

its go to activies table... if i change the tables on migrate file to activies, then the other method gone wrong because it's can't found activities. and this problem just happen to my store method, another method just do the right thing... is there any body can help me?

**Update:** Added from comments:

```
public function store(StoreActivityRequest $request) {
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required|unique:activies'
    ]);
    Activity::create($validatedData);
    return redirect('/activities')->with('success', 'Tindakan Berhasil Ditambahkan');
}
```

Comment: can you show your Store method ?

Comment: it is searching klinik_app.activies where as it should be klinik_app.activities. Check for the spelling mistake specially in file name

Comment: Looks like a typo - are you manually using a table name in the store method, eg using plain SQL or DB queries instead of Eloquent?

Comment: `public function store(StoreActivityRequest $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'slug' => 'required|unique:activies'
        ]);

        Activity::create($validatedData);
        return redirect('/activities')->with('success', 'Tindakan Berhasil Ditambahkan');
    }`
here my store code @OnkarManvelikar

Comment: Comments are not good for code - I've copied that into your question.  OK so you're using Eloquent in the `store()` method, no problems there. But you're also using a custom Request, `StoreActivityRequest`, so we're going to need to see that too ... Are you using manual table names, plain SQL, DB queries etc in that file?  Edit your question and add that code.

Comment: i add it can you check it @Don'tPanic

Comment: There is a typo in your validation: `'slug' => 'required|unique:activies'` - that should be your table name, `activities`. I vote to close this question as a typo.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).